# calculate the variance of future value of a portfolio

Tags: variance

I am trying (with no luck so far) to calculate the variance of future value of a portfolio.
$E= \frac{(1+r)[(1+r)^{t}-1]}{r}$,
$r$ is normally distributed random variable.

How to calculate $\text{Var}(E)$?

Comment: voters: I believe a post about Var(g(r)) is on topic here.

Comment: Boris, please check the edited mathematics says what you intend.

Comment: the equation above is FV (future value), that is the expected value. this is E[FV]. the quastion is what is VAR[FV]?

Comment: Future value is not E(Future value). E(future value) = $E\left(\frac{(1+r)[(1+r)^{t}-1]}{r}\right)$, where $r\sim N(\mu_r,\sigma^2_r)$. That expectation is not trivial.

Comment: What do you mean "That expectation is not trivial"?

Comment: Your statement (edit: the comment that's now deleted) makes no sense. Let $g= \frac{(1+r)[(1+r)^{t}-1]}{r}$. You just said that $E(g)=g$, implying that $g$ is a constant (since $g$ always equals the same quantity), but then $r$ doesn't have a normal distribution. Further, if $g$ can only take one value as you suggest, then its variance is zero. I'm afraid your question must be properly clarified. What are the parameters of the normal distribution for $r$?

Comment: let me explain myself: if i invest 1$ every day in a stock, and its dayly return in  r∼N(μ,σ^2) so after t days i will have some amount of money. the FV of my portfolio will be (1+r)[(1+r)^t−1]/r. that is the expected value. theat expected value will hava some variance it i wish to colculate it.

Comment: Is the daily return exactly the same for every day?

Comment: yes  r∼N(μ,σ^2) for example μ=0.05% and σ=1%

Comment: Is the daily return - not it's distribution, but its actual realized value - exactly the same for day 1 and day 2 and day 3? If not, you need a different symbol for each day ($r_1,r_2,r_3,...$)

Comment: the daily return in random variable normaly distibuted with μ and σ^2 the daily return is difernet each day (like in real life)

Comment: In which case, you have a different random variable for each day's return. Are the daily returns independent?

Comment: yes they are independent

Comment: I don't think the expression in your question for the future value can be correct, because the returns are not constant.

Comment: the future value is correct. i get the same result with a monte-carlo simulation with random r from normal distibution. this is a very knowen equation in financial modeling.